# CSS using url() for asset where file is imported elsewhere

Tags: css, import

I am using url as backgroun-image i.e. `background-image: url("../assets/email.png")` however the css file that contains this is imported into another css file in a different location and hence is it saying it can't find the email.png image. Is there a way to address this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

try inserting the full path directory to the image in your url(.)
and make sure it is the correct path.